# example of sub-harmonic function

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-functions

A continuous function $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is sub-harmonic if for every $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$
$$u(x_0) \leq \frac{1}{|\partial B(x_0,r)|}\int_{\partial B(x_0,r)} \!\!u(x)\ d\sigma(x)\ .$$

Using only this definitions, how could I prove that $x\mapsto|x|$ is sub-harmonic?

Comment: **Hint:** if you show what you've tried or what is giving you trouble, the question might get more upvotes.

Comment: I tried to play with triangular inequality, but I didn't obtain anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the [Triangle Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) to show $\left|\frac{x+y}{2}\right|\le\frac12|x|+\frac12|y|$ and integrate over a sphere.

**Hint 2:** Integrate $|x_0|\le\frac12|x|+\frac12|2x_0-x|$ over the sphere centered at $x_0$ noting that $2x_0-x$ is the point opposite $x$.

Comment: Should I integrate in $d\sigma(x)\ d\sigma(y)$ over $\partial B(x_0,r)\times\partial B(x_0,r)$ ?

Comment: @qwertyuio: I have tried to clarify in the second hint.

Comment: Now I've understood. Thank you a lot robjohn!

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove that $|x_0| \le \frac{1}{|\partial B(x_0,r)|} \int_{\partial B(x_0,r)} |x|dx$.

Now, $x_0 = \frac{1}{|\partial B|}\int_{\partial B} x_0 =  \frac{1}{|\partial B|}\int_{\partial B} x \le  \frac{1}{|\partial B|}\int_{\partial B} |x|$. The last term is positive, therefore taking the modules the result follows.

Comment: This is Jensen's Inequality using the convexity of $x\mapsto|x|$ (which is what my hint was trying for) (+1)

Comment: I would call it monotonicity :D

Comment: I don't see why  $\frac{1}{|\partial B|}\int_{\partial B}x=x_0$.

Secondly, does Jensen inequality hold for vectors too?

Comment: @user67133: $x\mapsto|x|$ is not monotonic, even when $n=1$. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: I was talking about the monotonicity of the integral, anyway sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @qwertyuio: the mean of the coordinates of the sphere is the center of the sphere. Yes, Jensen holds for vector valued functions as arguments to convex functions (continuous and $f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\le\frac12f(x)+\frac12f(y)$)